# c# - nested loop for random teleportation locations in UNITY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement, nested-loops

I am trying to teleport an object to different locations in a specific order in Unity, but the system is not going through the nested loop for the next teleportation location. I preallocated the teleportation locations in 2d array expecting the system to go over the 2d array through the nested loop and move the object accordingly, but it just moves the object to SP3 location regardless of the elements in the track_teleporation_index.  So I assume there is an error in the if-else if statements in nested for loops, but as a beginner in coding and Unity, I can't figure out the solution after days of troubleshooting.

Any help or lead will be greatly appreciated!

Her is my code:

```
public class Teleporting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject mouse;
    public Transform SP1; //Starting Position in Track 1
    public Transform SP2; //Starting Position in Track 2
    public Transform SP3; //Starting Position in Track 3
    private int[,] track_teleportation_index;


    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        mouse = GameObject.Find("mouse");

        track_teleportation_index = new int[3, 3] { { 1,2,3 }, { 3, 1, 2 }, { 1, 2, 3 } }; 

        for (int row = 0; row < track_teleportation_index.GetLength(0); row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < track_teleportation_index.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                if (track_teleportation_index[row, col] == 1)
                {
                    mouse.transform.position = SP1.transform.position;
                }
                else if (track_teleportation_index[row, col] == 2)
                {
                    mouse.transform.position = SP2.transform.position;
                }
                else if (track_teleportation_index[row, col] == 3)
                {
                    mouse.transform.position = SP3.transform.position;
                }

                Debug.Log("Teleported to track #" + track_teleportation_index[row, col]);
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Would you please edit this so that all of your code is in a code block?

Comment: Also, I have a question. what exactly is the debug log showing when you run through this?

Comment: just edited! and the debug log shows the the teleportation locations in first low in separate lines (so "teleported to track #1", "teleported to track #2", and "teleported to track #3") but it always teleports to sp3 regardless of the debug log or 2d array

Comment: Ah. I see. It's probably teleporting to all of them, but I bet it's just doing it so quickly you don't notice. Have you tried putting a `Thread.Sleep()` or a breakpoint to slow down your code, that way you can see what happens on every iteration?

Comment: putting a breakpoint after the debug.log line doesn't do anything.. also, even if I change the index so that the teleportation location order is 3,1,2, it will still be teleporting the object to track 3 only although the debug. log changes to "teleported to track #3", "...#1", and "...#2"

Comment: Hmmm, I'm trying to replicate the error and I can't.... Would you humor me? Try changing every row to be `{3, 2, 1}`

Comment: So what's wrong with this code? You have written a nested loop that finally moves the mouse position to sp3 home on the last line. Do you want the movement to be delayed or what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @JoshHeaps Ah ha! I changed the last row to be {3, 2, 1} and now it is repeatedly teleporting to the track 1. So for whatever reason, debug.log is logging the locations in first row, and teleportation loop is teleporting the object to the track location in last row, last column

Comment: @KiynL so I want the nested-loop to go through each element in the 2d-array (track_teleportation_index) and teleport the object to the corresponding track each time it is going through the array. So for example, if track_teleportation_index = {3,2,1}, the object will move to track 3 for the first time it hits the target, to track 2 as it hits the target after running on track 3, and lastly to track 1 as it hits the target after running on track 2.

Comment: Your cpu processes this instantly leaving the mouse.transform.position as the last iteration - it's what KiynL said

Comment: I see. Do you have any suggestions to go through one element in the 2d array each time the object hits the target instead of going through the entire 2d array when the object hits the target?

Comment: Assuming you just want to sequentially advance through the array of positions with each `OnTriggerEnter`, I'd probably suggest an internal index counter. What should happen when the player hits the trigger more than 9 times?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want is

- first time you hit the trigger -> go to SP1
- second time you hit the trigger -> go to SP2
- third time you hit the trigger -> go to SP3
- fourth time you hit the trigger -> go to SP1
- etc

A single counter would be enough for this

```
// Simply reference as many target Transform as you need
public Transform[] SPS;

// index for the NEXT target
private int index;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    // is the mouse not the same object that collides? 
    // in that case you would rather simply do
    //mouse = other.gameObject;
    mouse = GameObject.Find("mouse");

    // teleport to currently next target
    mouse.transform.position = SPS[index].position;

    Debug.Log("Teleported to track #" + SPS[index], SPS[index]);
    
    // Update to the next index, wrapping around at the end of array
    index = (index + 1) % SPS.Length;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In this case, should I use List<Transform> for SPS? and will the index be 1d array instead of 2d?

Comment: Serialization wise `List<T>` and `T[]` is basically the same. Since on runtime it shouldn't dynamically change I would go with `T[]`  and yes this would be a flat array .. I don't really see/understand your need to have that 2D array of indices (which is basically what you have there)  you only need a single index and operate on that one

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would iterate through each location in your 2d array, once every time `OnTriggerEnter` runs. This example will change a lot of your code, but will have the desired functionality. I'll try to explain what it's doing, and how it works.

```
public class Teleporting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject mouse;

    /*
    * If you want just the three starting points, you would need to do
    * this where ever you are setting them now.
    *
    * StartingPoints.Add(StartingPointOne);
    * StartingPoints.Add(StartingPointTwo);
    * StartingPoints.Add(StartingPointThree);
    * 
    * Using a list makes it so you can add as many starting points as 
    * you would like, as well as cleans up the rest of the code a bit
    */
    public List<Transform> StartingPoints { get; set; } = new List<Transform>();
    private int[,] track_teleportation_index;

    // Don't mind the underscore. It's something I picked up from the Microsoft documentation. 
    // It doesn't change functionality
    private int _row; 
    private int _column;

    public Teleporting()
    {
        //Set these to zero when instantiating the class
        _row = 0; 
        _column = 0;
        
        //Set this in here to not make a new one every time the method is called
        track_teleportation_index = new int[3, 3] { { 1,2,3 }, { 3, 1, 2 }, { 1, 2, 3 } }; 
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        mouse = GameObject.Find("mouse");

        // This code will move to the next position in your 2d array, 
        // regardless of the size of the array. This will only work
        // for a non null, 2d array.
        _row++;
        
        if (_row > track_teleportation_index.GetLength(0))
        {
            _row = 0;
            _column++;
        }

        if (_column > track_teleportation_index.GetLength(1))
        {
            _column = 0;
        }
        
        // Now get the starting point at the new location
        int desiredStartingPoint = track_teleportation_index[_row,_column];
        
        // Move mouse to the new location. If the desired starting point
        // equals three, then it will be set to the third element added
        // to the list.
        mouse.transform.position = StartingPoints[desiredStartingPoint];

        Debug.Log("Teleported to track #" + desiredStartingPoint);
    }

}
```

## Edit:

Here's some clarifying information about your comment.

To add new starting points to the `List<Transform>`, in the example above, that list is called `StartingPoints`, you would use the `.Add()` functionality of lists. This allows you to add a new `Transform` to the list. Using your your code mixed with the changes I made, here's how I would do it.

```
public List<Transform> StartingPoints { get; set; } = new List<Transform>();

public Transform SP1; //Starting Position in Track 1
public Transform SP2; //Starting Position in Track 2
public Transform SP3; //Starting Position in Track 3

public Teleporting()
{
    //Set these to zero when instantiating the class
    _row = 0; 
    _column = 0;

    //Set this in here to not make a new one every time the method is called
    track_teleportation_index = new int[3, 3] { { 1,2,3 }, { 3, 1, 2 }, { 1, 2, 3 } }; 

    StartingPoints.Add(SP1);
    StartingPoints.Add(SP2);
    StartingPoints.Add(SP3);
}
```

Doing this will make those first three starting points accessible. You can add more starting points to that list from any class that has access to the `Teleporting` class. Here's an example of what that might look like:

```
public class MyClass
{

    public Teleporting teleporting = new Teleporting();
    
    public Transform SP1; //Starting Position in Track 1
    public Transform SP2; //Starting Position in Track 2
    public Transform SP3; //Starting Position in Track 3

    public AddStartingPoints()
    {
        teleporting.StartingPoints.Add(SP1);
        teleporting.StartingPoints.Add(SP2);
        teleporting.StartingPoints.Add(SP3);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Josh for your answer! A quick question, how can I add different starting points to the List<Trasnform>? and where would I have to put those lines?

Comment: Great questions! I will edit my answer, then let you know when it's done

Comment: I've made an edit to clarify things

Comment: To your edited code, I changed "mouse.transform.position = StartingPoints[desiredStartingPoint];" to "mouse.transform.position = StartingPoints[desiredStartingPoint].position;" as it gave an error code "cannot implicitly convert type UnityEngine.Transform" to "UnityEngingVector3. But this new code gives another error as the object is approaching the target. An error message pops up saying "ArgumentOutOfRangeException: index was out of range. must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." and the object continues moving without teleportation.

Comment: Do you have any idea where this error comes from?

Comment: The out of range happens because I made a mistake. Just subtract `desiredStartingPoint` by 1. I'll look into the conversion problem

Comment: Instead of `mouse.transform.position = StartingPoints[desiredStartingPoint].position;` try `mouse.transform.position = StartingPoints.ElementAt(desiredStartingPoint - 1).position;`

Comment: I still get the same error message. In case it further clarifies, here's the full message "ArgumentOutOfRangeException: index was out of range. must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." "parameter name: index"

Comment: Note that `StartingPoints[desiredStartingPoint]` is still wrong since you are using `1, 2, 3` but array indices are `0` based and would need to be rather `0, 1, 2` ... `ElementAt` isn't really required for this either .. simply `StartingPoints[desiredStartingPoint - 1].position`

Comment: @jyeo3159 what line does it throw that on?